# RSpec request specs with an API key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, testing, rspec

I can't find anything on this. How do I pass an API key in my RSpec request tests?

My API Key is sent in a header, so I pass it like this in the web:

```
Header: Authorization
Value: Token token="c32a29a71ca5953180c0a60c7d68ed9e"
```

How do I pass it in an RSpec request spec?

Thanks!!

Edit:

Here is my spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "sessions" do
  before do
    @program =FactoryGirl.create(:program)
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    FactoryGirl.create(:api_key)
  end
  it "is authenticated with a token" do
    put "/api/v1/users/#{@user.id}?user_email=#{@user.email}&auth_token=#{@user.authentication_token}", {user: {name: "New Name"}}, { 'Authorization' => "Token token='MyString'" }
    response.status.should be(201)
  end

  it "fails without an API Token" do
    put "/api/v1/users/#{@user.id}?user_email=#{@user.email}&auth_token=#{@user.authentication_token}", user: {name: "New Name"}
    response.status.should be(401)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you share your specs?  It depends on how you are calling things.

Comment: Sure thing! I just posted them. The first spec is failing, returning a status code of `401`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I was very close. I needed to log the output from making an actual API call to see what the exact format the server was expecting for the HTTP Header. So, the problem was that the format was a little off.

```
describe "sessions" do
  before do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @api_key = FactoryGirl.create(:api_key)
  end

  it "is authenticated with a token" do
    put "/api/v1/users/#{@user.id}?user_email=#{@user.email}&auth_token=#{@user.authentication_token}", {user: {name: "New Name"}}, { "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"=>"Token token=\"#{@api_key.access_token}\"" }
    response.status.should be(201)
  end
end
```

As you can see I had to change the format from : `{ 'Authorization' => "Token token='MyString'" }` to `{ "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"=>"Token token=\"#{@api_key.access_token}\"" }`

I also just replaced `'MyString'` with the more robust reference to the actual instance of the api token. `@api_key.access_token`